# Counting hdfs compressed files greater than 100MB

Tags: hadoop, awk, grep, hdfs, bigdata

Can someone help me to build the command to give the count of `.snappy` compressed files from the Root directory in **HDFS** which are greater than 100MB?

I used this command to get the count of .snappy files from the root directory:

```
hdfs fsck / -files | grep ".snappy" | wc -l
```

Now I need to count the compressed files that are greater than 100MB.

Comment: The answers you have received so far contain horrible, non-idiomatc awk. If you post some sample input (i.e. the `hdfs` output) and expected output for the tool you want to create then people who know awk can help you, otherwise you'll be stuck with only answers from people who know `hdfs`, whatever that is, not people who know awk.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of hdfs and awk commands should do this. Here is the snippet

`hdfs dfs -ls -R /path_to_dir/ | awk '{if ($5 >104857600 && $8~/\.snappy/) print $8}'`

Comment: I am using 256Mb block size and there are more smaller files. What size files should I start compressing and is there any industry standard for compressing a file thats lesser than a particular size?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one liner using awk:

```
hadoop fs -ls -R /|grep "snappy"|awk -F" " '{ if( $5 >= 104857600 ) print $5" "$8 }'
```

Comment: I am using 256Mb block size and there are more smaller files. What size files should I start compressing and is there any industry standard for compressing a file thats lesser than a particular size?

Comment: That is completely different question. There is no industry standard as such. You need to understand compression algorithms and choose right one.